# Python Pandas | Create separate lists for each of the columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, tolist

I am not sure how to use tolist to achieve the following. I have a dataframe like this:

```
Param_1     Param_2     Param_3
-0.171321   0.0118587   -0.148752
1.93377     0.011752    1.9707
4.10144     0.0112963   4.06861
6.25064     0.0103071   5.83927
```

What I want is to create separate lists for each of the columns, the list name being the column label.

I don't want to keep doing:

```
Param_1 = df["Param_1"].values.tolist()
```

Please let me know if there's a way to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `.T`

```
df.values.T.tolist()
Out[465]: 
[[-0.171321, 1.93377, 4.10144, 6.25064],
 [0.0118587, 0.011752, 0.011296299999999999, 0.0103071],
 [-0.148752, 1.9707, 4.06861, 5.83927]]
```

Or we can create the `dict`

```
{x:df[x].tolist() for x in df.columns}
Out[489]: 
{'Param_1': [-0.171321, 1.93377, 4.10144, 6.25064],
 'Param_2': [0.0118587, 0.011752, 0.011296299999999999, 0.0103071],
 'Param_3': [-0.148752, 1.9707, 4.06861, 5.83927]}
```

Or using `locals` (Not recommended but seems like what you need)

```
variables = locals()
for key in df.columns:
    variables["{0}".format(key)]= df[key].tolist()
Param_1
Out[501]: [-0.171321, 1.93377, 4.10144, 6.25064]
```

Answer (score 2):

Can also `agg`

```
>>> df.agg(tuple)

Param_1               (-0.171321, 1.93377, 4.10144, 6.25064)
Param_2    (0.0118587, 0.011752, 0.011296299999999999, 0....
Param_3                (-0.148752, 1.9707, 4.06861, 5.83927)
dtype: object
```

If really need `lists`,

```
df.agg(tuple).transform(list)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `dictionary` with column name as key, you can try:

```
result = df.to_dict(orient='list')
# result will be: 
# {'Param_2': [0.0118587, 0.011752, 0.011296299999999999, 0.0103071], 
#  'Param_1': [-0.171321, 1.93377, 4.10144, 6.25064], 
#  'Param_3': [-0.148752, 1.9707, 4.06861, 5.83927]}
```

You can also use `as_matrix` which will return `numpy` `ndarray`, as below:

```
result = df.as_matrix().T
# result will be:
# [[-0.171321   1.93377    4.10144    6.25064  ]
#  [ 0.0118587  0.011752   0.0112963  0.0103071]
#  [-0.148752   1.9707     4.06861    5.83927  ]]
```

To get `list` from `ndarray`:

```
result = df.as_matrix().T.tolist()
```